# How to best structure an abstract class where a member field will depend on the deriving type?

Tags: c#

Puts and calls are two types of options. One parameter that they both share is called a strike price. The valuation of an option is related to the strike price, but the exact methodology is different depending on the type of option. All things being equal, a lower strike price is better when valuing a call, and vice versa when considering a put. I am considering the best way to model my code so that these comparisons could be performed as simply and intuitively as possible.

Ideally, I would like to be able assign optionInstance1.Strike = 5, and to evaluate if optionInstance1.Strike > optionInstance2.Strike while considering the rules of the particular type of option. I am trying to explore the best ways to accomplish this.

The first approach: attach an evaluator class to every option instance

```
interface IOptionRules
{
    bool GTE(decimal s1, decimal s2); 
}

class CallRules : IOptionRules{ ... }

abstract class Option
{
    public decimal strike; 
    public IOptionValuationRules rules;

    public Option(decimal strike, IOptionRules rule){ this.strike = strike; rules = rule;}
}

class CallOption : Option
{
    public CallOption(decimal strike) : base(strike, new CallRules()){}
}
```

this would allow for easy assignment => strike = 5m
but comparisons would be cumbersome and unintuitive => optionInstance1.Rules.GTE( optionInstance1.strike, optionInstance2.strike);
it would not preclude direct comparison operators => optionInstance1.strike >= optionInstance2.strike

The second approach: perform the evaluations in a completely different class

```
class OptionEvaluator
{
    public bool GTE(CallOption o1, CallOption o2){} 
    public bool GTE(PutOption o1, PutOption o2){}
}
```

It seems this approach invites maintenance issues in the future, for example if I were to create any sort of exotic options with special rules in the future, I would have to remember to update this separate class. Furthermore, I think with this approach I would have to upcast whenever I am working with Option Types.

The third approach: defining a strike type

```
abstract class Option
{
    public Strike strike; 

    public Option(Strike strike){ this.strike = strike;}
}

abstract class Strike
{
    public decimal Amount{get; set;}
        public abstract bool GTE(decimal otherStrike);
}

class CallStrike : Strike{...}

class PutStrike : Strike {...}
```

This seems to be a desirable approach, but the main issue I have is how cumbersome it would be to assign a strike amount as it would make more sense to type OptionInstance1.Strike = 4 rather than OptionInstance1.Strike.Amount = 4.

Also, I would potentially be able to assign a PutStrike to a CallOption at runtime since the type of the strike field is Strike, although I suppose this is easily fixable if I made it readonly.

Are there any other approachs for this particular issue? Are there particular issues that I am not considering with any of these approachs? Which is the best approach to take?